# Revisions limit

Tags: templating, craft3

To extend the revisions limit I currently edit the "vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_includes/**revisionmenu.html**" file. But I have to do it after each Craft CMS update.

Is there a better way to do it, so the craft updates won't affect it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [maxRevisions](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#maxrevisions) config option you might find useful:

```
'maxRevisions' => 10,
```

Comment: yes, I've tried changing that option however it doesn't affect the revision menu UI in the CMS. It always shows only 10 revisions there.

IT seems like the only way to show more than 10 revisions in the CMS is to change "limit" value in the file I mentioned above. The code looks like this there:

`{% set revisions = element.find().revisionOf(element.sourceId).siteId(element.siteId).anyStatus().offset(1).limit(10).all() %}`